# npm install eslint missing argument error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, eslint

Am trying to install eslint locally in a project folder. However installing as mentioned on https://eslint.org

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

returns the following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-70-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "eslint" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ashish/Documents/Web-Development/Bootcamp/auth-test/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried installing eslint globally, and also without saving the dependency to package.json but the same error message appears.

npm doesn't return an error for any other package (express, request etc.). This seems to be happening only with eslint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your npm version is too old (4 years old),  you need to update it

```
npm i -g npm
```

Also consider updating `node`, version 8 is `End-of-life` since 31 Decembre 2019.
https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Answer (score 13):

I have tried above but it, unfortunately, didn't work for me. The other way could be this:

1. Update nodejs to latest version:

   ```
   sudo npm install -g n
   sudo n latest
   ```
2. Update npm to latest version:

   ```
   sudo npm install -g npm
   ```
3. Do what @runcible suggested:

   ```
   hash -d npm
   ```
4. Try npm install:

   ```
   npm i
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For me the suggested solutions above didn't worked to install a newer version of node. I did it with curl. Here for Node 15.x newest so far

```
sudo apt install nodejs

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt install nodejs
```